# PHP y MySQL Obtener multiples selects checked checboxes

Tags: php, mysql

Necesito obtener de la base de datos, a un usuario especifico con todos los intereses que tenga en la tabla[a_users_has_interest], y mostrarlos en Checkbox, pero también quiero mostrar todos los Intereses a la vez, y los intereses de los usuario sean seleccionados

**Algo como esto:**

[image: Ejemplo]

**Nota:** Tengo las siguientes tablas, adjunto el SQL y el ejemplo del código

a_interest: Todos los intereses

a_users: Todos los usuarios

a_users_has_interest: Todos los usuarios que tienen intereses

```
-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for a_interest
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `a_interest`;
CREATE TABLE `a_interest` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- ----------------------------
-- Records of a_interest
-- ----------------------------
INSERT INTO `a_interest` VALUES ('1', 'Deportes');
INSERT INTO `a_interest` VALUES ('2', 'Salud');
INSERT INTO `a_interest` VALUES ('3', 'Belleza');
INSERT INTO `a_interest` VALUES ('4', 'Amor');
INSERT INTO `a_interest` VALUES ('5', 'Internet');

-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for a_users
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `a_users`;
CREATE TABLE `a_users` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- ----------------------------
-- Records of a_users
-- ----------------------------
INSERT INTO `a_users` VALUES ('1', 'User 1');
INSERT INTO `a_users` VALUES ('2', 'User 2');

-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for a_users_has_interest
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `a_users_has_interest`;
CREATE TABLE `a_users_has_interest` (
  `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `interest_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`,`interest_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- ----------------------------
-- Records of a_users_has_interest
-- ----------------------------
INSERT INTO `a_users_has_interest` VALUES ('1', '1');
INSERT INTO `a_users_has_interest` VALUES ('1', '2');
INSERT INTO `a_users_has_interest` VALUES ('1', '3');
INSERT INTO `a_users_has_interest` VALUES ('2', '1');
INSERT INTO `a_users_has_interest` VALUES ('2', '2');
```

**Mi código de ejemplo para obtener los datos:**

```
SELECT *
FROM a_users_has_interest UHI
LEFT JOIN a_interest I ON I.id = UHI.interest_id
WHERE UHI.user_id = '2'
```

Esto me muestra el usuario con las opciones pero quiero mostrar todos los intereses con y los intereses que el usuario tenga aparezcan con su ID del interes y los intereses que no, entonces esten vacios.

*Agradezco mucho su ayuda*

Comment: No debes especificar explicitamente los `id` a la hora de insertar. Para eso haz marcado el campo como `AUTO_INCREMENT`. Deja que mysql lo haga internamente.

Answer (score 2):

Lo que puedes hacer es invertir el `LEFT JOIN` de la siguiente forma

```
SELECT I.id, 
       I.name, 
       CASE WHEN UHI.user_id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END as 'HasInterest'
FROM a_interest I
LEFT JOIN a_users_has_interest UHI 
  ON I.id = UHI.interest_id
  AND UHI.user_id = '2'
-- ORDER BY I.id
ORDER BY 'HasInterest', I.id
```

Esto te muestra todos los intereses y un `1` en caso que el `user_id = 2` lo tenga como uno de sus interes y `0` en caso contrario. Algo así:

```
id  name        HasInterest
=== =========== ===========
1   Deportes    1
2   Salud       1
3   Belleza     0
4   Amor        0
5   Internet    0
```

En cuanto al orden, puedes elegir que siempre aparezcan con el mismo orden o primero desplegar los items seleccionados.

Comment: Excelente, me parece muy bien si conoces alguna otra forma de hacer esto para los usuario como o que todavía no conocen el uso de condicionales en MySQL sería de gran ayuda pero manten este por favor por que es muy interesnte tu ejemplo